# What is ChangeDetectionStrategy in Angular2 and when to use OnPush Vs Default?

Tags: angular

I happened to see `ChangeDetectionStrategy` in the [ngrx documentation](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510#taking-advantage-of-changedetectiononpush). It uses `OnPush`.

What is `ChangeDetectionStrategy` in Angular2, and when to use OnPush Vs Default?

Comment: check this [article](https://vsavkin.com/change-detection-in-angular-2-4f216b855d4c?gi=334feaf37382)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `OnPush` strategy if your objects are immutable and you don't change the state of the objects in your component. It will perform better rather than default where each change of the object makes run change detector to resolve changes. More or less similar is described in [Change Detection Strategy: OnPush](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html)

> To inform Angular that we are going to comply with the conditions mentioned before to improve performance, we will use the `OnPush` change detection strategy

The Angular docs said

> ### [ChangeDetectionStrategy:](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectionStrategy-enum.html)
>
> - `OnPush` means that the change detector's mode will be set to `CheckOnce` during hydration.
> - `Default` means that the change detector's mode will be set to `CheckAlways` during hydration.

Comment: Does it mean ```OnPush``` is used if the developer manually manage the change detection, and default is when Angular2 does?

Comment: Manually doesn't make sense which strategy is used.

Comment: What is `hydration`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It's a change detector is doing.

Answer (score 22):

All above answers explain `OnPush` and `Default`, here I post an example about how it really works:
https://plnkr.co/edit/hBYb5VOrZYEsnzJQF5Hk?p=preview

user-one.component.ts :

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-one',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    <div>
      <h4>{{ user.name }}</h4>
      <h5>{{ user.age }} years old</h5>
      {{ user.location }} <br />
      {{ user.email }}

      <button (click)="update()">Internal update</button>
      <p>* should not update</p>
    </div>
  `
})
export class UserOneComponent {
  @Input()
  user;

  update() {
    this.user.name = 'Lebron James';
  }
}
```

user-two.component.ts :

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-two',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
  template: `
    <div>
      <h4>{{ user.name }}</h4>
      <h5>{{ user.age }} years old</h5>
      {{ user.location }} <br />
      {{ user.email }}

      <button (click)="update()">Internal update</button>
      <p>* should update</p>
    </div>
  `
})
export class UserTwoComponent {
  @Input()
  user;

  update() {
    this.user.name = 'Kevin Durant';
  }
}
```

Every time we change object properties like 'this.user.email' or 'this.user.name', UserTwoComponent would always update the changes but UserOneComponent only change when we have a new user object.

If you change the properties inside of each component, it inherit the ChangeDectectionStrategy, for instance, if we change this.user.name inside UserOneComponent both names in UserOneComponent and UserTwoComponent would change, but if we change name inside UserTwoComponent, only name inside UserTwoComponent would change

Answer (score 7):

I saw a really nice and simple explanation in that link:

http://www.codecompiled.com/change-detection-in-angular-2/

`ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`:
it will update the view only in specific scenarios:

- When some event is fired inside the component.
- When the value of input changes.

`Default` means: check for all properties in the view and Always update the view.

Comment: What's `always` on top what is above specified?

Answer (score 5):

This example can help you understand it:

[change_detection_strategy_onpush](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html)

[angular2-with-immutablejs-and-redux](https://houssein.me/redux/immutablejs/angular/2016/07/04/angular2-with-immutablejs-and-redux.html)

> So what really happens when an event is triggered? In Angular 1.x, when a digest cycle is fired, every binding is triggered in the entire application. Similarly in Angular 2, every single component is also checked. Now wouldn’t it be cool to tell Angular to run change detection on a component only if one of its input properties changed instead of every time an event happens? We can by using Angular’s ChangeDetectionStrategy in our component level.

OnPush just focus on input properties, Default check all properties.

Answer (score 3):

Change detection is a feature provided by angular framework which is responsible for checking the changes happing in between the specified component with parent child relationship.

1. Change detection makes angular application more efficient you use it wisely.

2.It has two strategy onPush and Default.

3.**OnPush** Strategy gets executed when the specified object in component gets modified.Otherwise it remains as it's. That's why It makes efficient.

4.**Default** strategy makes application to work gets executed whenever it finds changes.