# ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush doesn't act how I expect it to

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get familliar with angular 2's `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` performance boost (as explained [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)). But I have curios case here.

I have parent `AppComponent`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>
  <app-literals [title]="title" [dTitle]="dTitle"></app-literals>
  <input [value]="title.name"/>
</h1>
`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = { name: 'original' };
  dTitle = { name: "original" };

  constructor(private changeDetectorRef : ChangeDetectorRef) {

  }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      setTimeout(() => {
        alert("About to change");
        this.title.name = "changed";
        this.dTitle = { name: "changed" };
      }, 1000);
    }

}
```

And child `LiteralsComponent` component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-literals',
  template: `  {{title.name}}
  {{dTitle.name}}`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class LiteralsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('title') title;
  @Input('dTitle') dTitle;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I thought setting strategy to `OnPush` made angular only reflect changes of references but in a sample I tried changing (mutate) a property of an object and angular still reflects it.

`this.title.name = "changed";` shouldn't be detected (thus the UI shouldn't not reflect the change).

Here is the case on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zjgnXVJIg0m3Zb1EBYcX?p=preview)

How comes? How to do it right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is ChangeDetectionStrategy in Angular2 and when to use OnPush Vs Default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542639/what-is-changedetectionstrategy-in-angular2-and-when-to-use-onpush-vs-default)

Comment: I'm not asking what it is, I read about it and think I got it according to the book, I'm just not figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What causes the code in your question to be executed? Your question doesn't provide enough information. OnPush executes change detection when an change detection updated the value of an input or when an event happens inside the component.

Comment: Remove `this.dTitle = { name: "changed" };`

Comment: I mutate title instead of changing the whole object. That's why I excpect OnPush to prevent angular2 from seeing the property has changed.

Comment: In your plunker you changes object

Comment: I do this.title.name = "changed" and in my template I have {{title.name}}. Angular2 has to inspect inside "title" to know "name" changed. Yet ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush should prevent this kind of inspection's depth.

Comment: Are you sure? http://take.ms/sBefe

Comment: As I wrote in my above comment, there are cases where Angular runs change detection even with OnPush. If these cases apply isn't clear from the small amount of code you provided.

Comment: dTitle reference change but title reference doesn't. Yet both {{title.name}} and {{dTitle.name}} are updated.

Comment: read [this article on change detection](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) which explains how `onPush` works under the hood

Comment: @SergeBuSI, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43540983/2545680) and tell me if there's anything unclear

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, _or when an event happens inside the component_ - what kind of event?

Comment: @yurzui, he is not updating the right object

Comment: @Maximus He is running change detection by changing reference in parent component

Comment: @Maximus https://plnkr.co/edit/DnXP8TG9XZ257vT0TRes?p=preview If at least one of property has changed in parent component then component with OnPush change detection will run change detection He changed `dTitle` reference that is why his component is updated

Comment: @yurzui, ah, yeah, I misunderstood the question. He is asking why the update if the object reference hasn't change, correct?

Comment: Yes. That is. He wants only property to be updated but angular changes state for component and all view will be updated http://take.ms/GoBHk

Comment: @Maximus a DOM event that Angular listens to. Not entirely sure if it only counts if the component itself has an event binding or if the event originates within the component but a parent has a binding.

Comment: @Maximus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795634/angular-2-change-detection-and-changedetectionstrategy-onpush/39795679#39795679 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312075/change-detection-issue-why-is-this-changing-when-its-the-same-object-referen/42312239#42312239

Comment: @yurzui, I've figured it out, please see [my updated answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43540983/2545680). I also find this question very interesting and informative for the public. I'll edit question details

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I've figured it out, please see [my updated answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43540983/2545680). I also find this question very interesting and informative for the public. I'll edit question details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're asking why the bindings value is updated in `LiteralsComponent` template even if you don't modify the reference `title`, but rather mutate the object.

**The short answer** is that because you modify both:

```
this.title.name = "changed";
this.dTitle = {name: "changed"};
```

in the `AppComponent.ngOnInit`. If you modify only `this.title.name = "changed"` you will see that template is not updated.

**However, this is a very interesting question to explore in details**

Let's first start with only `this.title` without `this.dTitle`. 
The first thing to understand is that when you specify the following in the template:

```
{{title.name}}
```

here is what Angular does. It tries to find `title` object on current component instance, and then gets `name` property from it and reflects it in the DOM. But with the following configuration:

```
class AppComponent {
    title = { name: 'original' }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      setTimeout(() => {
        alert("About to change");
       this.title.name = "changed";
    }, 1000);
}
}

class LiteralsComponent {
     @Input() title;
}
```

the `title` object is **the same** in both components (point to the same memory location).

So when Angular runs change detection for the `LiteralsComponent` component, it accesses the same object that you're changing here in `AppComponent`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert("About to change");
    this.title.name = "changed";
  }, 1000);
}
```

The interesting observation here is the change **isn't detected** at all neither with `OnPush` nor without it:

```
class LiteralsComponent {
     @Input() title;

     ngOnChanges(changes) {
         // will be triggered only for the first CD cycle,
         // and won't be triggered when `title` is updated
     }
}
```

Now, the last thing is to understand is when the DOM is updated. According to [this article](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f), it's updated during CD for the current component. It means that if the current component isn't checked, the DOM won't be updated. So we specify `onPush` for the `LiteralsComponent`:

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
```

the view won't be updated.

**But, it's updated in your question. Why?**

And this where `dTitle` comes into play. With this property, you're actually modifying the reference and Angular **detects bindings changes** and runs CD for the `LiteralsComponent` component. And we learnt above that when CD is run, the DOM is updated. So Angular also updates `{{title.name}}` since it points to the same object in `AppComponent`, although **it didn't detect it was changed**.