# What does Strategy OnPush mean?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I am new to Angular2 with TypeScript. I am currently working on a project and unfortunately, cannot understand what does OnPush do:

> changeDetection : ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

I have searched a lot, but did not find (did not understand) the correct answer.

Can anybody explain it to me? Example could be appreciatable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is ChangeDetectionStrategy in Angular2 and when to use OnPush Vs Default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542639/what-is-changedetectionstrategy-in-angular2-and-when-to-use-onpush-vs-default)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On push change detection means that the change detection on the component is run only when the inputs change, and when the inputs change, their whole object must change. What that means is if only the reference changes the change detection will not be run.

For example if you have an input on a component that is an array:

```
@Input() testArray: Item[] = [];
```

If you modify that array in the parent component with `push`, change detection will not run on the child component. But if you do something like this:

```
array = [...array, newItem];

<test-component [testArray]="array"></test-component>
```

Change detection will run. This is used to increase your application performance as it greatly reduces the number of times change detection runs. It is normally paired with **immutable** data structures and especially `Redux` patterns with `store` such as `@ngrx/store`.

Comment: it's not a question of whole Object or not but that the change comes from the parent on an `@Input()` property. "What that means is if only the reference changes" even if you change "the whole object", this is a reference change.

Comment: Well, thank you. I guess that is a very good description. So, I have to write it on the child(the component which expecting a value), correct?

Comment: @SamySammour Your components should be following the smart/dumb principle if applying OnPush detection. Meaning that all things such as getting data, modifiying data should be done in the smart component, and dumb components should only be used for the presentation. This means that your child component should just have an input(like above), and any modification should be done in the parent component the way I showed you.

Comment: @Matsura, very clear. Thank you. I really understand why my components reacting in this way then.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to understand with an example:

You have a component with an Input attribute:

```
type Person {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
}
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    template: `<p> {{person.name}} {{person.surname}} </p>`
})
class myComponent {
  ...
  @Input() person: Person;
  ...
}
```

If you modify the initial value of the person with something like

```
person.name="changed";
```

Angular won't detect that change because it considers that the object itself is the same. You have changed an attribute of the object, not the object itself. You need to change the whole object (the reference) to make Angular to detect this change:

```
person={name:'changed',surname:'something else'};
```

So it's like angular considers input elements as immutable objects and any change inside them will be ignored.