# how child component is updated using onpush?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular2-changedetection

I am understanding how onPush change detection works in angular. Much of the concept I am cleared. But there is one thing which I am also finding hard to get on Google.
Scenario,

Suppose we have a parent component passing some values to child component and child component have onPush change detection strategy and that child component have a button performing some task not emitting anything to parent.

When we click on that button from child component change detection works from Root component to that parent component and then it seems that there is no reference change in child component so it should not execute the change detection in the child component from where the button was clicked because the reference is not changed.
But it executes there as well.

Here I am confused can anyone help me to make it more clear.

Comment: could you please sample code snippet in stackblitz to replicate your issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is ChangeDetectionStrategy in Angular2 and when to use OnPush Vs Default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542639/what-is-changedetectionstrategy-in-angular2-and-when-to-use-onpush-vs-default)