# Angular Async Pipe not subscribing to initial value of EventEmitter

Tags: angular

With Angular's `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` I try to use the Async-Pipe / subscribe to observables whenever I can - right? So instead of binding to my value like `{{value}}` I'd rather use `{{valueChange | async}}` what is working pretty fine, except for initial values. I think the event is emitted before the template is loaded and so it doesn't get the initial value:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9wbvu

What is the best practice to solve this? Or am I wrong with my understanding of `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @M1CH3L1US above, this isnt an issue regarding the changeDetectionStrategy. The changeDetectionStrategy affects how the change detection is triggered. There are multiple explanation to the various changeDetectionStrategy in this thread.

[What is ChangeDetectionStrategy in Angular2 and when to use OnPush Vs Default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542639/what-is-changedetectionstrategy-in-angular2-and-when-to-use-onpush-vs-default)

Regarding your question, there are a few solutions

1. Use a different Angular lifecycle hook to trigger your initial value,  something like AfterViewInit would work

```html
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  setRandomValue(): void {
    this.value = new Date().toString();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.setRandomValue();

}

  @Input() set value(v: string) {
    this._value = v;
    this.valueChange.emit(this._value);
  }
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
  public _value: string;
}
```

2. Use of BehaviorSubject.

This method will allow your Observable to actually store a value, preventing any race conditions.

```html
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  value$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  setRandomValue(): void {
    const newValue =  new Date().toString()
    this.value$.next( newValue )
    this.value = newValue
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setRandomValue();
  }
  
  ngAfterViewInit(){

}

  @Input() set value(v: string) {
    this._value = v;
    this.valueChange.emit(this._value);
  }
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
  public _value: string;
}
```

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<p>
  Current Value non async: {{_value}}
</p>
<p>
  Current Value: {{value$ | async}}
</p>
<p>
  <button (click)="setRandomValue()">ChangeValue</button>
</p>
```

3. Lastly, you really have to ask yourself if you need the value asynchronous? If the value if passed in via @Input as per your example, you will always get the actual value that is being passed into the component. Hence you might not event need  that additional complexity

Comment: Thank you for your super well-founded answer! Guess you're right with your #3! But anyway, regarding your second solution with the `BehaviorSubject` (I really like): as far as I know the idea of using `EventEmitters` is, that Angular automatically cleans up dependencies, subscriptions etc. when the component is destroyed. I'm afraid using `BehaviorSubjects` in templates could break this behavior?

Comment: Another questions, hope it's not too off-topic: is there a mode where Angular **only** checks on explicit `ChangeDetectorRef` call (manual of by async pipe)? Guess that could speed up the page a lot! I actually don't need by `@Inputs` to be checked if I just use `AsyncPipe`.

Comment: 1. I  believe the Async pipe in the template automatically unsubscribes upon the destruction of the component

2. I dont think there is, the only 2 change detection strategy that i know of are the default and onPush strategies. I believe onPush would be sufficiently performant enough for you. However there are ways to execute your code outside to not trigger any ChangeDetection, You can read up more about Angular Zones.

Answer (score 1):

At the point where you subscribe to the `EventEmitter` (Or rather Angular subscribes to it by virtue of the async pipe), the code in `ngOnInit` was already run. The `EventEmitter` extends a Subject which does not save the value of the most recent state. By subscribing to it after the first value has already has been emitted you will not be *notified* by the that first value. I suggest you move the startup code into `ngAfterViewInit` which would make the initialization run after the view has been rendered and the subscription to the event emitter was already bound by Angular.

Side note:
I just notices that changing the value in `ngAfterViewInit` would not be optimal as this would change component state after the view has been checked. To make sure you're on the save side I suggest you ask Angular to run change detection again after you set the component state:

```
class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private readonly cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {  }
  
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.setRandomValue();
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

The `ChangeDetectionStrategy` has nothing to do with it here as there is no change in state that Angular could know about.

Hope this makes sense :3

Comment: Yes, works for me. And detectChanges is not necessary when using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` since the AsyncPipe calls `MarkForCheck`. I guess you ran into the default ChangeDetectionStrategy issue. But is this still the cleanest solution? Seams hacky somehow. Or is this just how it is done?

Comment: You're absolutely right. You won't need to manually request change detection again if you're using the `OnPush` stragegy. If you're using OnPush this doesn't seem all that hacky to me as you basically only change `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: As for your comment on @wscttc answer, you can use the `detach()` method of the `ChangeDetectorRef` to remove the current view from the change-detection tree. Which I think is what you're looking for.